# how to use callback functions in angularjs

Tags: javascript

```
function A(){
    return 10;
}
console.log(A);
console.log(A());
```

- What will happen here?
- will `A` return only 10?
- what will `A()` do here?
- Is callback functions same in `javascript` and `angular`?

Comment: angularjs is written in javascript, I don't see what would be different. What kind of callbacks are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(A);` will show a function that will return 10 once executed.

`console .log(A());` will execute function A() first, which will return 10 as an output; therefore, it will be console.log(10). Finally, it will show 10 as an Integer.